# SHA1 encryption and SHA1 to Hex in php

Tags: java, php, sha1, password-encryption

I have two methods in Java and I want to do the same methods in php. I don't know absolutely nothing in php. How can I do it?

Method 1:

```
public static String encyptPassword (String in) throws UnsupportedEncodingException, NoSuchAlgorithmException{
    byte[] bytes=in.getBytes("UTF-8");
    MessageDigest md=MessageDigest.getInstance(MGF1ParameterSpec.SHA1.getDigestAlgorithm());
    md.update(bytes);
    byte[] digest=md.digest();
    return toHex(digest);
}
```

Method 2:

```
public static String toHex(byte[] bytes) {
    BigInteger bi = new BigInteger(1, bytes);
    return String.format("%0" + (bytes.length << 1) + "x", bi);
}
```

The methods (function?) in php must have the same result as in java, because it's **hashing** passwords for a working and online login system.

I'm trying it about 3 hours, but I can't do it or found a solution. I think I read all posts on Stack. Can you help me? Thanks.

Comment: Be aware that hashing passwords with SHA* is unsecure, especially unsalted, because it is ways too fast. SHA1 can be brute forced with a speed of [30 Giga SHA1/second](http://hashcat.net/oclhashcat/#performance), that's why one should use a slow hash function with a cost factor like BCrypt or PBKDF2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**[PHP Fiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/c5vb-f9ad)** - *hit run to see the result*

```
<?php

    $pass = 'MySecretP@55';
    $hashed = hash("SHA512", $pass);
    echo $hashed;
    echo '<hr>' . bin2hex($hashed);

?>
```

Above is `sha512`, which is certainly better that `sha1`, and bcrypt with reasonably high cost is considered as the best currently

Comment: Thank you all for helping me. I choose your response because you told me how to hash and how to hex it. @Sammitch is a good answer with pretty good link that I will study. gregn3 give the same response. Again, thank you all.

Comment: You welcome and I'm glad it helped, what @Sammitch wrote considered best practices, `sha1` produces 40 characters and for easy and known passwords it's so crack-able with brute-force or rainbow or such techniques, there are several websites that offers "*decrypting*" them for free, i.re: https://hashkiller.co.uk/sha1-decrypter.aspx, `sha512` is a better it produces 128 characters, but if you use it with dynamic salting that improves it much better, the new built-in password_hash($string) is currently a best choice . enjoy coding

Answer (score 2):

1. [Hashing != Encryption](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4948393/1064767)
2. SHA1 is weak, SHA2 is better, bcrypt is currently the best generally-available hashing algorithm for password storage.
3. `$myHash = hash("SHA1", "foobar")` [Docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.hash.php)
4. Don't use #3, use `$myActuallySecureHash = password_hash("foobar")` [Docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php)
5. Use #4.
6. [PHP < 5.4 is not an excuse.](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat)

Comment: Ok. It's hashing password. Do you know a way to `toHex($myActuallySecureHash)` ?

Comment: @Alan How about `$hex = bin2hex ($myActuallySecureHash);` ?